# Tensorflow - running CPU-only eval process throttles GPU training process

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training a TF model on my home PC. I am trying to evaluate my model during training using a parallel TF process so that the main trainer doesn't have to stop intermittently. My idea is to force the eval process to use the CPU only - the main process doesn't use all the cores of my machine (task manager shows 12%) as it's GPU bound.

The CPU-only process disables CUDA with

`os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'`

To make sure the eval process doesn't interfere with the main training process, I restrict the number of CPU cores it's allowed to use with this:

```
    session_config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=allowed_core_count,
                                    inter_op_parallelism_threads=allowed_core_count,
                                    allow_soft_placement=True, device_count={'CPU': 1})
    run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(log_step_count_steps=20,
                                        save_checkpoints_secs=FLAGS.save_checkpoint_secs,
                                        session_config=session_config)
    estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, model_dir=FLAGS.job_dir, config=run_config)
```

Looking at the actual CPU utilization by both processes shows that the above works well.

However, even though total CPU utilization is well below 100% (depending on the allowed core count) and the eval process doesn't use GPU at all, **the main training process suffers immensely when the eval process is running**. The OS shows that GPU usage, previously steady at 100%, now fluctuates between 60% and 100%. So something in the eval process is interfering with the training process.

[image]

What is it and how can I prevent this from happening?

I doubt it's a disk issue - both the eval and training process run off big shuffle buffers that last for hundreds of training steps.